# How to extract date from string

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, date

I'm working on PostgreSQL with SQL.

I have a column date that is a string and I want to extract the month:

[image]

I tried:

```sql
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM cast(date as date)) FROM table_name ;
```

I got:

> ERROR: ERREUR:  syntaxe en entrée invalide pour le type date : « janvier 2020 »

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: please don't post images of data see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: These are not valid dates, so you cannot cast them to date. Use substring or regexp_replace.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: if the right locale is configured, it should be possible to convert them to proper dates using `to_date(..., 'TMMonth yyyy')`: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6ae039b9844b18390d5147293ef2b1e6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
select  
    split_part(date, ' ', 2) as month
from table_name
```

.